# CSS Nth Child For Use In Quoting Messages

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am creating a message system in which users can quote the messages of other users. It works fine for one quote but when I have multiple quotes I would like to be able to visually distinguish between them.

I am using the "nth child" selector to try and give each 2nd quote block a different visual style ie even row.

I have the following HTML structure for a post containing 4 quotes inside it ie one quote quoting another.

```
<div class='post_container'>
<blockquote><cite>Quote: user1</cite>

<blockquote><cite>Quote: user2</cite>

<blockquote><cite>Quote: user3</cite>
<blockquote><cite>Quote: user4</cite>

<p>post1</p>
</blockquote>
<p>post2</p>
</blockquote>

<p>post3</p>
</blockquote>

<p>post4</p>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

**The CSS code I am using is as follows:**

```
.post_container blockquote{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.post_container blockquote *:nth-child(even){
    border:thick;
    background-color:#3FF;
}


.post_container blockquote>cite{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:#999999;   
}

.post_container blockquote *>div:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#3FF;
}
```

**Here is how it looks in HTML currently:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5Jjxj/6/

Comment: It's not entirely clear what layout you are wanting, but it becomes a little clearer if you use blockquote:nth-child(even) instead of *:nth-child. I think you probably need to restructure your HTML though, and what you need to do depends ultimately on the layout you're looking for.

Comment: I've simplified it a bit so now there is no div inside the blockquote just the cite then the quoted text. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: If you're looking to style every nth nested element, that's not possible using `:nth-child()`. You may have to repeat the blockquote selectors manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.post_container blockquote:nth-child(even) *`

instead of `.post_container blockquote *:nth-child(even){`

Comment: Thanks much appreciated for your answer that did the trick :)

Comment: On second thoughts it only works for the first quote after that it doesn't.

Comment: because you changed your html code, if you could explain the effect you pretend would be easier, which elements exactly are not displaying correctly?

Comment: See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Jjxj/6/ Your code only worked if I had 2 quotes.